# ComboBox selected item string comparison doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making an application that consists of `comboBoxes`. If the user selected "Chauffeur" in the `comboBox` the total price goes up by 10% once my `btnAddDriver` is clicked. However when I select "Chauffeur" the total price does not increase by 10% when I click Add Driver in fact when using brake points it doesn't seem to realise I have selected "Chauffeur" and skips the calculation within the if statement.

My Code is as fallows

```
 int policy = 500;
 double Chauffeur = 0.10;

        private void cmbOccupation_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // ... A List.
            List<string> occupation = new List<string>();
            occupation.Add("Chauffeur ");
            occupation.Add("Accountant");


            // ... Get the ComboBox reference.
            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

            // ... Assign the ItemsSource to the List.
            comboBox.ItemsSource = occupation;

            // ... Make the first item selected.
            comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

     private void btnAddDriver_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            txtPolicy.Text = policy.ToString();

            if (cmbOccupation.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Chauffeur")
            {
                txtPolicy.Text = (policy * Chauffeur).ToString();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Don't compare strings, use enums for something like this. Or class instances that you save in accessible references for complex types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `occupation.Add("Chauffeur ");`

To `occupation.Add("Chauffeur");`

Answer (score 2):

`"Chauffeur"` and `"Chauffeur "` are two different strings in C#.

That'll be $150, please pay the girl at the desk on your way out.

Comment: Or use `Trim()` before making a comparison.

Comment: @Rahul And `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` for good measure. But I'd really just use an enum like H.B. says.